# Distributing (proper) iOS frameworks with dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, app-store-connect

Let’s consider the following scenario: The app “MyApp” is using an SDK provided by a propretary MySDK.framework. In turns, the MySDK relies on open source libraries like AFNetworking and RESTKit.
In order to distribute MySDK, the developer needs to provide all the dependencies since, for example, RESTKit requires AFNetworking 1.x and it’s not compatible with version 2.0.

In a pre-framework scenario, the libraries used by MySDK would be all embedded into the binary of the framework and obviously shipped together.
If MyApp needs to use AFNetworking or other libraries, these will be embedded in the app’s binary. In case of shared libraries between MyApp and MySDK, the code will be duplicated and embedded both into MyApp’s binary and MySDK’s binary. For this reason, there’s no clash if MyApp needs AFNetworking 2.x since each binary will embed its own version.

Enter frameworks.
With frameworks, each library is compiled into a separate .framework and that is linked at runtime to the code using it. In order to distribute MySDK with all the dependencies, the framework bundle contains all the dependencies as “sub”-Frameworks inside MySDK.framework/Frameworks directory.
Same happens for MyApp that will have MySDK framework inside MyApp.app/Frameworks together with swift libraries and all the other dependencies specific of MyApp.

If such an app is uploaded to iTunes connect, the server rejects it with the following reason: “Validation Error: Invalid Bundle. The bundle at [MySDK.framework path] contains disallowed file ‘Frameworks’”.
It seems like iTunes only accepts the first level of Frameworks, then one embedded directly into the app’s bundle, but I can’t find that rule written anywhere.

The alternative is to flatten the Framework hierarchy and ship all the MySDK dependencies together with MySDK.framework and let MyApp devs include them into the App’s bundle with a copy frameworks phase.
This creates a different problem: we’re now in a scenario where there can be only one version of each library so if MySDK needs AFNetworking 1.x the app won’t be able to use AFNetworking 2.x since all frameworks are at the same leve and there’s no namespace.
In order to fix that, one solution is to  create a versioned framework for AFNetworking and include both versions. Unfortunately that means we will then need to maintain a different bundle for each version of the libraries each time they come out. Cocoapods doesn’t support versioned frameworks so we would also be preventing users of MySDK from using it. Even in that case, how can we specify at compile time which version of a framework a binary should link to?
MySDK.framework is not a self-contained unit anymore and its stability depends on external actions like importing the right dependencies into the app. This doesn’t sound great.

What are the options?
I really want to embrace .frameworks/@import on our code since that’s where Apple's heading, but I feel like the only trouble free path for now is using now obsolete and inefficient static-libraries.

Comment: It is 2018 and still no answer. Did anyone solve this?

Comment: Still no answer?

Comment: Was there ever a resolution or alternative found for this?

Comment: No good answer so far and after 7 years I moved on from iOS development. The world has moved on and Swift static linked libraries are not “obsolete” as I said in the post. I’ve just read a very well written blog post that sums up the problem as it stands in 2022 quite nicely: https://belkadan.com/blog/2022/02/Dynamic-Linking-and-Static-Linking/